# Importing blender model to unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, blender, modeling

I'm new in Unity 3D and Modeling. I created a blender model already but cannot correctly import it. I'm choosing the objects I need and then importing FBX into unity at it looks like this(screenshots). I have no idea what I have to do. It also doesn't import emission for the "Welcome text".

[image: how it should look]

[image: how it looks]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**

### For multiple objects u have some different things to do

**

For multiple models in a single Blender file, it’s probably easier to export each one as an FBX file (like you already make it) and then import them one at a time. With one model per file, importing the Blender file directly should be just fine. Just keep in mind that, once imported, a native Blender file will change whenever the original is modified in Blender.
Is very important to know if you are importing right, for make sure:

> 1. With the model opened, in the right side-bar region, go to the “Transform” tab.

> 2. Set all the rotation axes (X, Y, Z) to 0°.

> 3. Set all the axis scales (X, Y, Z) to zero 1,0.

> 4. Select the “Cursor Tool” in the top left.

> 5. Select the new origin on the model by clicking where you want to place it.

> 6. Go to “Object > Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor”.

These last steps aren’t mandatory, but they can really save time once the model is imported to Unity, especially when importing multiple times.

[Setting a new origin example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9Ejf.png)

Next, we’ll make sure all the model’s normals are pointing outwards, as some surfaces might be invisible in Unity if they aren’t oriented accordingly

> 7. Go to “Edit Mode” and select all faces.

> 8. Go to “Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside”.

> 9. Save your file.

And it's all for Blender, let's go to unity

### Importing an FBX File to Unity

[Importing an FBX file to Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBKIQ.png)

For this, we first need to export the model to an FBX format. To do that, while we’re still in Blender:

> 1.Go to “File > Export > FBX (.fbx)”.

> 2.In the export window, enable “Apply Transform” by clicking on the checkbox. This will make the coordinate system from the model work with Unity’s system.

> 3.Click on “Export FBX” in the top right.

Try this, and let me know if it does not work

Comment: Yeah, it helped me a lot ! Thank you !